# How to add ability to return XML as response for dynamic object in .NET Core

Tags: c#, json, xml, asp.net-core, serialization

I am trying to add the ability to return XML to my .NET Core API. The built-in serialization seems not to work with dynamic structure. I wonder if there is any suggestion to work around this?

```
    public class Response
    {
        public IEnumerable<object> Projects { get; set; } = new List<object>();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to serialize dynamic object to xml c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757808/how-to-serialize-dynamic-object-to-xml-c-sharp)

Comment: The Net library XML serialization requires classes that match the XML schema.  So you need a different set of classes for each XML structure.  If you are using a controller, the controller can support multiple different return types provided you have a classes for each type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serialize dynamic object to xml c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757808/how-to-serialize-dynamic-object-to-xml-c-sharp)